# Attempting to respond to events with discordrb, how events are handled seem to be inconsistent

Tags: ruby, discord

I'm currently attempting to code a discord bot in ruby using discordrb. I'm trying to make it respond to events, but the official documentation (https://github.com/discordrb/discordrb/wiki/Events) tells me this is correct:

```
bot = Discordrb::Commands::CommandBot.new token: 'token', prefix: '/' #Token has to be hidden, but its correct
bot.channel_create do |event|
  lp "[SYS]:> **Channel created** | Name: #{event.name}" #Custom definition to send messages to a specific channel
end
bot.run
```

Doing this always returns this when a channel is created however:

```
[ERROR : et-2 @ 2020-09-12 00:20:25.383] Exception: #<NameError: undefined local variable or method `bot' for main:Object>
[ERROR : et-2 @ 2020-09-12 00:20:25.383] E:/starlight.ai/main.rb:26:in `lp'
[ERROR : et-2 @ 2020-09-12 00:20:25.383] E:/starlight.ai/main.rb:35:in `block in <main>'
[ERROR : et-2 @ 2020-09-12 00:20:25.383] C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/discordrb-3.3.0/lib/discordrb/events/generic.rb:98:in `call'
[ERROR : et-2 @ 2020-09-12 00:20:25.384] C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/discordrb-3.3.0/lib/discordrb/bot.rb:1316:in `block in call_event'
```

I'm not sure how to progress from here, since apparently events are separated but I don't know how to access them (I'm not used to reading rubydoc.info documentation). Does anyone know how to access these events?

Comment: Show us your code. Not just those three lines, show us the surrounding code. Make a [mre].

Comment: I updated it with what you asked @anothermh

Comment: Please read the above-linked article again, then come back and include a minimal reproducible example.